# Mac Catalyst app crashes on launch if application will/didFinishLaunching methods exist

Tags: swift, macos, appdelegate, mac-catalyst

I've a really weird problem here.

My Mac Catalyst app is crashing on launch with the following exception within AppDelegate.swift:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: title)'
```

Some info is that the project is a **Mac Catalyst** app ported from an **existing** iOS/iPadOS app, and it does *not* use SwiftUI and does *not* use multiple scenes. The exception occurs in the AppDelegate class.

However, the debugger points to the line of class declaration, and not to any of my written code, thus I believe it's an internal error.

Interestingly, I've dug around a bit and have determined that the moment I removed the `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` and `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` methods from my AppDelegate, the app runs just fine. Even an empty declaration like so:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

will cause the app to crash, whereas *not including the method at all* would allow the app to run just fine.

Here's the stack trace:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: title)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35ac5d07 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6e7ea5bf objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35b7463e -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35b7f19c -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:].cold.3 + 0
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35a03459 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 976
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff764748eb -[_UIMenuBarItem properties] + 99
    6   UIKitMacHelper                      0x00007fff66bf872a UINSNSMenuItemFromUINSMenuItem + 90
    7   UIKitMacHelper                      0x00007fff66bf8340 _insertUINSMenuItemsIntoNSMenu + 1135
    8   UIKitMacHelper                      0x00007fff66bf7da8 UINSNSMenuFromUINSMenu + 119
    9   UIKitMacHelper                      0x00007fff66bf7c49 -[UINSMenuController _createNSMenu:forContextMenu:] + 79
    10  UIKitMacHelper                      0x00007fff66bf7b09 -[UINSMenuController setMainMenuBar:] + 70
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff764687d6 -[_UIMenuBarController _rebuildRootCommandGroup] + 229
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff763113a2 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 801
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff76310a33 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 5775
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff7630de2b -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1319
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff7630d7fb -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 122
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff76308a07 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 83
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff7630cf45 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 198
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff7630cd28 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 467
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff7630bf21 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 823
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff7630bb42 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 350
    21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff7678e853 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke_2 + 178
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff7630a0a3 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 832
    23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff763095f2 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 240
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff763092bf __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 153
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff7630920c _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 84
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff76308f4a -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 379
    27  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff763083cb __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 685
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff76307aef -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 262
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff763079a4 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 210
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff762fa3b8 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 524
    31  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff762fa122 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    32  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff5225a25d -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 453
    33  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff5225a083 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.156 + 102
    34  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff52259f02 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 220
    35  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff52259b0d __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 354
    36  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010091e826 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    37  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100922070 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 289
    38  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff52259996 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    39  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff52259766 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 441
    40  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff52259593 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35a49f12 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35a49eb1 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 103
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35a49ccb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 209
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35a489fa __CFRunLoopRun + 927
    45  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff35a47ffe CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 462
    46  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3467babd RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
    47  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3467b6f4 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 359
    48  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3467b579 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
    49  AppKit                              0x00007fff32cc6c99 _DPSNextEvent + 883
    50  AppKit                              0x00007fff32cc54e0 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1352
    51  AppKit                              0x00007fff32cb71ee -[NSApplication run] + 658
    52  AppKit                              0x00007fff32c88ff6 NSApplicationMain + 777
    53  AppKit                              0x00007fff32faaa85 _NSApplicationMainWithInfoDictionary + 16
    54  UIKitMacHelper                      0x00007fff66bf4e00 UINSApplicationMain + 322
    55  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff762db6ff UIApplicationMain + 2130
    56  <Project Name>                      0x00000001002222db main + 75
    57  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6f991cc9 start + 1
    58  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm not able to recreate this issue with a new Xcode project.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `CFBundleName` might be missing from your `Info.plist`.

The hint is in the error:

> `[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: title)`

Comment: Thanks! I've resolved the issue. For me, it appears there was a misspelling in CFBundleName.

How do you relate the error mentioned to the fact that CFBundleName may be missing though? I would like to learn how to understand and resolve these errors in the future.

Comment: @LWJ: The debugger is the best place to determine what is happening with your app.  The place in which you mentioned it was crashing (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) and the key `title` pretty much tells me (from experience) that it's related to the title or name of your application. So the first place to look would be where that is set, which happens to be `CFBundleName`.